# How does one read a confirmed spl-transfer transaction's instructions?

Tags: transactions, spl-token, spl-token-program

Creating an spl-transfer transaction:

```
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  createTransferInstruction(
    // Pretend this is filled in
  )
)

const signature = await sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(..)
```

Assuming I only have access to `signature`, how can I confirm the transaction's sender, recipient, token transfer amount, and the token's public key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [getTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransaction) method on the `connection` class to get details on the transaction with a signature.

```
async function getTransactionFromSignature() {
  // setup code for example
  const connection = new web3.Connection(
    web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"),
    "confirmed"
  );
  // end setup code

  const signature =
    "4x96CKaqStrBSW436RuTp4H7qFC4tACfQDMdWJm8LWBHTnXVf7yUdvE4J5btcz63RiC7Pnk7SP4P8QckLsh8rEh5";

  const response = await connection.getTransaction(signature);
  const message = response.transaction.message;
  const meta = response.meta;

  console.log(message, meta);
}
```

From the [meta](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#ConfirmedTransactionMeta) and/or [message](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Message.html) you can make the assertions you want.

There's a full example in the [Solana Pay](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/master/core/src/validateTransfer.ts) code on how we validate transfers for SOL or SPL tokens